# Nuget Packages global location on Linux

Tags: .net, linux, build, package, nuget

Nuget Packages global location on Linux

We are using a shared server(build server) for multiple projects and during dotnet build, the Packages are being saved at `/home/useraccount/.nuget/packages/` directory and we do have limited space at /home directory.
We would like to these packages to go to `/opt/ghe/useraccount/.nuget/packages/` folder rather than /home dir.

Tried below solutions but no luck -

Added this as Environment varaibles -
`NUGET_PACKAGES=/opt/ghe/useraccount/.nuget/packages/`

Modified both Nuget.config file at both the locations `/home/useraccount/.nuget/Nuget/` and `/opt/ghe/useraccount/.nuget/Nuget/` with below -

`<config> <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="/opt/ghe/useraccount/.nuget/packages/" /> </config>`

Running this command as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders) gives this -

`$ ~/.nuget/packages -ksh: /opt/ghe/useraccount/.nuget/packages: cannot execute [Is a directory]`

Running the dotnet build from GitHub Actions, where runners are configured on this build server.

Is there any other place, I need to update for the nuget packages to be on /opt/ directory ?